# Are the new gang hideouts added in "The Liars and Cheats" DLC multiplayer-only?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

[The Liars and Cheats DLC](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/Liars_and_Cheats) ([Rockstar page](https://www.rockstargames.com/reddeadredemption/dlc/liars)) adds seven gang hideouts to the game. When visiting [Crooked Toes](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/Crooked_Toes) — an area with a distinct rock formation — both at night and during daytime there was no activity in the region. Do the hideouts only appear in the online multiplayer?

I have [the Game of the Year edition](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/19161/red-dead-redemption-game-of-the-year-edition-now-available-for-x.html) (includes all DLC) on Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

The Hideouts added by The Liars and Cheats DLC are only available in Free Roam (multiplayer).

As the [wiki](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/Gang_Hideouts) states:

> The Liars and Cheats DLC adds **seven hideouts to Free Roam** that are not available with the base game. Upon completion of any of the gang hideouts added by this DLC, an Explosive Rifle is awarded to the top player.

Comment: "not available with the base game" to me means the vanilla game as Liars and Cheats was a paid DLC pack. But it's now almost self-evident that the new gang hideouts are online-only.

Comment: @user598527 And thus your question is answered, and you should accept this answer ;)